# replace string on a specific column of multiple files from unix terminal

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have multiple tab delimited files with same column names. An example file is attached as a snapshot.

[image]

Now, I would like to replace every 'INV' in coloumn 4 with 'RAC'. I wrote the following awk code. However it does not work well. Can anyone check my code?

```
#!/bin/bash
path=path/to/dir/containing/the/files/to/be/processed
for file in `ls $path`
do
echo processing $file
awk '{ if ($4 == "INS") {$4 = "RAC"; print} else { print }; }'  $file>  ${file}_new.txt
done;
```

Comment: Please include sample input data as text. Anyone trying to help you will otherwise have to type in the data by hand.

Comment: This can be useful [http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218896/how-to-replace-value-for-a-given-condition-in-specific-column-of-file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218896/how-to-replace-value-for-a-given-condition-in-specific-column-of-file)

Answer (score 1):

Do not parse `ls output` as shown [[ here ]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

```
find /path/to/files -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | while read -r -d '' filename
do
awk '$4=="INV"{$4="RAC"}{print}' "$filename" > tempfile && mv tempfile "$filename"
done
```

would do it

Comment: @123 : Indeed.. Corrected that

Comment: Thanks! It worked now. I appreciate the suggestions.